# Array.index(of: can return nil But there's compile error when checking for optional value

Tags: ios, swift3

```
var countryCodes    = [String]()

let codeIndex = countriesList.index(of: countryTextField.text!)
        var chosenCountryCode? = countryCodes[codeIndex!]
```

that third line gives a compile error, saying it's a non-optional type. Documentation says `index(of:` can return `nil`.

How do I check for nil?

Comment: Why are you using "var chosenCountryCode?"   ?

Comment: Because I want the chosen country code to be a variable.

Comment: Swift is not Ruby, don't use `? or !` as suffix in the variable name. In Swift, you only put the  `?  or  !`  as `action` on Optional on the right hand side of `=`

Comment: If you find my answer and comment below acceptable, please accept and up vote it.  If you can't do that, please kindly explain the reason.  I will try my best to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how a working code for similar scenario would look like:

```
var countryCodes = [String]()

countryCodes = ["1000","1001","1002","1003","1004","1005","1006","1007","1008","1009"]

let countryList = ["Afganistan", "Argentina", "Armenia","Belgium","Brunei", "Bulgaria","Cambodia","Egypt","Yemen","Zambia"]


// assuming we get this from UI:
let countryTextField_text = "Egypt"

if let codeIndex = countryList.index(of: countryTextField_text) {
    let chosenCountryCode = countryCodes[codeIndex]
    print(chosenCountryCode)
}
```

Will output:  1007

Comment: And what if you tried for a country that didn't exist in the list?

Comment: Since we use `if let ` syntax,  and we don't provide  `else` then it will just ignore that.  That's the purpose of the Optional. If it's there  use it,  if not  then move on.   Btw. you could just cut and paste my code to Playground and play with any variation you like.